# How to insert several cells (not an entire row/column) using google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

Say I have a sheet with values in all visible cells. I want to insert cells above, say, C3:D3 so that the existing values in C3:D3 and below are moved downwards. I want the columns next to C3:D3 to remain unchanged. Is this at all possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible. You'd use [`insertCells()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#insertcellsshiftdimension):

```
function testInsertCells(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange("C3:D3");
  range.insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
}
```